# Android: Show users own uploads data

Tags: android, sqlite, authentication

I faced same problem as this post
[Showing users only their own uploads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14417090/showing-users-only-their-own-uploads)

I also have two databases one for the uploading stuff and another one for login, my question is how to do this query:
**SELECT * FROM photos WHERE author = AUTHENTICATED_USER_ID** in android sqlite.

Here is my original code in class of **SQLiteConnector** that can only show all the pictures.

```
public Cursor getAllItem() {
        db = sqlHp.getReadableDatabase();

        cur=db.query(ItemDb.TABLE,null, null, null, null, null, "name");

        return cur;
    }
```

**EDIT**

I try to do query as below but still having error, any idea pls??
**class of Activity**

```
private class GetItem extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Cursor> {
        ItemSQLiteConnector dbConnector = new ItemSQLiteConnector(ItemActivity.this);

        @Override
        protected Cursor doInBackground(Object... params) {
            return dbConnector.getAllItem(UserName);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Cursor result) {
            itemAdapter.changeCursor(result);           
        }

    }
```

**class of SQLiteConnector**

```
public Cursor getAllItem(String email) {

        db = sqlHp.getReadableDatabase();       
        cur=db.query(ItemDb.TABLE,null, "email="+ email, null, null, null, "name");     
        return cur;

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try this, assuming you have a string usename which contains the authenticated user id:

```
 String[] userID = new String[] {
     usename
 };

 cur = db.query("photos", null, "author = ?", userId, null, null, "name")
```

The first value, "photos" indicates which table.

The second value, "null", indicated that you want all columns.

The third value, "author = ?" is the selection filter, and userId is the value that it is comparing to.

The final "name" is the column that will be used for sort order.

Comment: userId is String[], but the value(usename) i pass is just string, so how?